# Ruby 2-dimensional arrays reject based on first item

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a two dimensional array

```
array = [["a first sentence of 6 words","Reference 1"],["another sentence that may be longer with 9 words","Reference 2"]]
```

I want to delete all entries whose first element contain less than 7 words so get the following array

```
[["another sentence that may be longer with 9 words","Reference 2"]]
```

I tried various things including

```
   array.reject { |a| a.first.split.size < 7 }
```

But I get the error

```
undefined method `split' for 0:Fixnum
```

I also tried

```
   array.reject { |a| a[0].split.size < 7 }
```

and

```
   array.reject { |a| a.first.size < 7 }
```

But it seems to create an endless loop and the page keeps loading with no result. Could anyone help me get the right syntax?

Comment: `array.reject { |a| a.first.split.size < 7 }` should work; maybe you are changing `array` value somewhere else? Check [this fiddle](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/3fd44).

Comment: Looks like one of the first elements is an array is Fixnum. split is not defined on Fixnum, hence error. array.reject { |a| a.first.to_s.split.size < 7 }

Comment: just add `to_s` after `a`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of the first elements in an array is Fixnum. split is not defined on Fixnum, hence error.

reject if the first item's to_s.split is less than 7.

```
array.reject { |a| a.first.to_s.split.size < 7 }
```

Comment: `!a.first` is redundant because of `to_s`. `nil.to_s` returns an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You could make this a bit more efficient by counting the spaces rather than creating an intermediary `Array`. You could also make this more readable by using parallel assignment. e.g.

```
 arr = [
        ["a first sentence of 6 words","Reference 1"],
        ["another sentence that may be longer with 9 words","Reference 2"]
       ]
# split with no argument will separate on space and create an Array
# this means we can use `String#count` and look for the number of spaces that would 
# create 7 words (e.g. 6 spaces) 
# `#strip` will get rid of leading an trailing spaces so that `#count` will work like `#split`
arr.reject {|sentence,_ref| sentence.to_s.strip.count(' ') < 6 }
```